# Using a defined function type in a function declaration

Tags: c, function, typedef

I defined a pointer to a function type:

```
 typedef uint32_t (*funct_t)(bool);
```

I declared a function that uses the same interface:

```
uint32_t a_funct(bool);
```

I need to use the pointer to a function type instead. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to declare a function using the function pointer typedef?

Comment: > Are you asking how to declare a function using the function pointer typedef?    ... Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define the typedef like this:

```
typedef uint32_t (funct_t)(bool);   // note the missing * before the type name
```

You can declare the function like this:

```
funct_t a_funct;
```

Note that when you define the function, you still need to spell out the parameters.

```
uint32_t a_funct(bool x)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I defined a function type:

```
typedef uint32_t (*funct_t)(bool);
```

No, you did not declare a function. You declared pointer to a function type.

To declare a function type you could write

```
typedef uint32_t funct_t(bool);
```

and then you can use the type to declare the function `a_funct`

```
funct_t  a_funct;
```

Take into account that you may not use a typedef of a function type to define a function.

Comment: You are right. I edited my post to make that correction. Thank you.