# exploit a function type to define a new function

Tags: c++, function, typedef, using

Curious to know whether there have ever been proposals to extend the language and exploit a defined function type in a function definition.
A related question is:
[Using a defined function type in a function declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41269283/using-a-defined-function-type-in-a-function-declaration)
where, of course, one of the comments indicated that a defined function type cannot be (currently) used in a function definition.

So, what cons for a future extension allowing the following code ?

```
using F = int(void);

F f{
  return 42;
}
```

Of course, this is just a simple case with no parameter names to deal with.

Comment: Complicates compiler impl. with no obvious benefit. That's what I see.

Comment: About benefit, I see the same as any typedef / using, which for functions is currently restricted to definitions only.

Comment: Any future extension to already overwhelmingly complex language is a drawback on itself. Atm committee seem to just drag into standard whatever they can find.

Answer (score 0):

> where, of course, one of the comments indicated that a defined function type cannot be (currently) used in a function definition.

I actually didnt check what comment you refer to, but as quoted the statement is not correct. You can use return and argument types of a function to infer return and argument types of another one. It just requires some boilerplate.

The following works in principle already in C++11:

A trait to get return type:

```
template <typename F> struct return_type;
template <typename R,typename ...Args> struct return_type<R(Args...)> {
    using type = R;
};
```

A trait to check argument types:

```
template <typename F,typename...Args> struct same_args : std::false_type {};
template <typename R,typename ...Args> struct same_args<R(Args...),Args...> : std::true_type {};
```

Using it:

```
using F = int(void);

template <typename ...Args>
std::enable_if_t<same_args<F,Args...>::value,typename return_type<F>::type> f(Args...) {
    return 42;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << f();
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8b7EaMMqT)

I am not aware of a shorthand notation you are asking for. It is already possible to define a function that infers its return and argument types from a given function. The drawback is of course that `f` is a template.

> So, what cons for a future extension allowing the following code ?

I see no particular reason why it would be totally impossible. Though, the usual considerations apply: Does it bring something new that cannot be done with existing facilities? Is it worth to add more complexity to an already complex language? Does it actually make code more readable? Imho no extension of the language is needed, because you can already define a function based on another functions return and argument types.

Comment: Thank you to remark about traits. When I expressed "a defined function type cannot be (currently) used in a function definition", I just meant in the way I showed in my original post for a raw function.

Comment: @user20575107 well, functions are not first-class citicens, you cannot do `F f;`

Comment: I know that you can declare "F f;" instead.

Comment: @user20575107 oh sorry, you can, but it doesnt do what one might expect. What I meant was that functions are not objects like other objects, like they are in other languages (eg python)

Comment: ok, I see your point. Agreed.